# Query Execution Plan Tool - Java

Tags: java, open-source, sql-execution-plan

Does anyone know an open source java solution to display the Query Execution plan of a query send to a database ? Would prefer a graphical output like a graph with nodes etc.

EDIT : Used Database is Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query plan is highly dependent on the database you use, so you are unlikely to find a generic app that will show you the execution plan for any query on any database. But if you add a bit of details about what database you are using, it will be easier to help you.